# reverse string using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Could anyone please explain why "return str" line never executes?

```
public static String reverseString(String str){
    String reverse="";
    if(str.length() == 1){
        return str; //at one point this condition will be true, but value never returns
    } else {
        reverse += str.charAt(str.length()-1) + reverseString(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
        return reverse;
    }
}

public static void main(String a[]) {
    System.out.println(reverseString("Test"));
}
```

Comment: `return str;` will only executed if the string has a length of 1, Test has a length of 4

Comment: Have you tried running your small example in a debugger?

Comment: the code is absolutely right... return reverse executes...

Comment: If you are using an IDE like eclipse, debug and see it enters `if (str.length() == 1)` when it gets `str = "T"` value during recursion calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line does executes, how can you say it does not executes. I have added the syso statement, it does print, actually you are calling `substring` in a recursion, once the length becomes 1, it will execute.

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {
        String reverse = "";
        if (str.length() == 1) {
            System.out.println("hi");
            return str; // at one point this condition will be true, but value never returns
        } else {
            reverse += str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + reverseString(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
            return reverse;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        System.out.println(reverseString("Test"));
    }
```

**output**

```
hi
tseT
```

Comment: when the length becomes 1, shouldn't it print the value of "str" as well?

Comment: @VijayNandwana it is recursive method, method call for `reverseString` is from else part, carefully observe it, so `return str`, will return to else part not from whole method ..

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I missed that part. I was wondering that when the if condition becomes true then else block will not execute, but in this case method has been called from else block hence it will get execute. Understood. Thank you Ankur.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use [StringBuilder#reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) method

```
public String reverser(String str){
   return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: Please explain the code in an answer. Even if this works (I think it is), an explanation can help OP to correct his solution better than copying and pasting. (Also this doesn't answer the actual question on "why doesn't this function end properly?")

Comment: @Vesper that is a built-in class in Java. check the API-Doc from the above link. If you are interested you can check the source code as well from rt.jar file

Comment: The line added is a decent explanation as is. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {
    String reverse = "";
    if (str.length() == 1) {
        return str; // at one point this condition will be true, but value
                    // never returns
    } else {
        String part = reverseString(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
        System.out.println("Current: " + part); // Print out
        reverse = str.charAt(str.length() - 1)
                + part;
        return reverse;
    }
}

public static void main(String a[]) {
    System.out.println(reverseString("Test"));
}
```

Just add a print within your recursive function, to trace what is happening.

**Output:**

```
Current: T      // return str
Current: eT     // return reverse
Current: seT    // return reverse
tseT            // final return reverse
```

From the output, you can convince yourself whether str is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

My Implemention:

```
    public static String reverse(String str) {
        if(str.length() > 1) {
            return str.substring(str.length()-1)+reverse(str.substring(0, str.length()-1));
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverse("Test"));
    }
```

output:

```
tseT
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it hits and executes, check this out;

```
public static String reverseString(String str){
    String reverse="";
    if(str.length() == 1 ){
        System.out.println("HIT: " + str);  // CHECKING HIT
        return str; //at one point this condition will be true, but value never returns
    } else {
        reverse += str.charAt(str.length()-1) + reverseString(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
        return reverse;
    }
}

public static void main(String a[]) {
    System.out.println(reverseString("Abcd"));
}
```

If you run this code, you will see the output as below;

```
HIT: A
dcbA
```

To Understand how this code is working, you have to understand how reverse method call itself and completes its process;

Check the image down below;

[image]

As you can see, on the 3rd step, because that the recursive function's input string length equals to 1, that part of the code is executed.

Hope that all these helps.

Comment: Thank you Levent for explaining the method flow with diagram.